# How can I run an API call AFTER the results from my useSelector() hook?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to use some data that will come from my `useSelector()`hook in a network API call. However, with the code below, I get the error `TypeError: cannot read property 'query' of undefined.`
I understand this is because the query has not come back from the useSelector()
yet. Is there a way I can wait for that data THEN call the API?

> ```
> const pageContent = useSelector(getPageContent);
>
> useEffect(() => {
> axios
> .get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', {\
> params: {
> key: process.env.API_KEY,
> part: 'snippet',
> type: 'video',
> q: pageContent.data.query,
> },
> })
> .then((res) => res)
> .then((data) => console.log(data));
> }, []);
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use useEffect with pageContent as dependency, so whenever pageContent has changed, the api will be get call

```
useEffect(() => {
if(!pageContent){
  return;
}
axios
.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', { params: {
  key: process.env.API_KEY,
  part: 'snippet',
  type: 'video',
  q: pageContent.data.query,
},
})
.then((res) => res)
.then((data) => console.log(data));
}, [pageContent]);
```